# ArcMap 100k meters square identification - double?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, grids-graticules

ArcMap - 1:50.000 - 5x3 meters - MGRS

I put on a grid defined with the standard 1:50.000 grid style in ArcMap.

I tick the box for "100,000 meter grid square identification", but it makes it double... See image. I never intended to do it double, I just want one set of grid square identifications.

[image: Grid Square Identification Problem]